# How to align data based on time?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm using pandas (python library) to analyze a set of data.
My job is to align this data based on time.
I'll explain:
I have different switches that give me a 1 or 0 if is pressed or not and
after being pressed, it returns to the previous stateby itself afterwards some time, and  there are different switches. These data are saved in csv file with the date and time of the status. 
my goal is to view the switches states, of a day, in a diagram like this:
https://ibb.co/RgJbq9J

The switches can be press in any time of a day and my problem is that i'm can't align the data in the diagram.

data example

```
datetime 1          switch 1    datetime 2      switch 2
08/12/2018 13:21:08    0    08/12/2018 10:15:59    1
08/12/2018 13:24:33    1    08/12/2018 10:18:13    0
08/12/2018 13:29:54    0    08/12/2018 10:29:28    1
08/12/2018 13:34:43    1    08/12/2018 10:31:37    0
08/12/2018 13:39:01    0    08/12/2018 10:34:01    1
08/12/2018 13:40:49    1    08/12/2018 10:36:14    0
08/12/2018 13:43:04    0    08/12/2018 10:37:05    1
08/12/2018 13:44:51    1    08/12/2018 10:39:19    0
08/12/2018 13:47:07    0    08/12/2018 10:40:03    1
08/12/2018 13:51:20    1    08/12/2018 10:42:15    0
08/12/2018 13:53:30    0    08/12/2018 10:42:51    1
08/12/2018 13:53:39    1    08/12/2018 10:45:14    0
08/12/2018 13:55:58    0    08/12/2018 10:52:29    1
08/12/2018 13:57:08    1    08/12/2018 10:54:49    0
08/12/2018 13:59:27    0    08/12/2018 11:01:01    1
08/12/2018 13:59:54    1    08/12/2018 11:05:32    0
```

[image: output graph example]

This is what is my goal, to display all the switches in a graph plotted day by day.
The graph is not related to the data in previous table.

Comment: You can try using `pd.to_datetime()` to convert the time date into a specific format and then `df = df.sort_values(by=['<time column>'])` to order it by the column.

Comment: The data is already ordered by time, the problema Is the viewing all the data together, with the same axis x. All the switch have One CSV file with calura and datetime and my goal Is tonview all the switches having the same scale of axis x that Is time.

Comment: @YatD3siB0y try `pd.merge` Or give some sample data here.

Comment: @YatD3siB0y I agree with Sid.  It would be pretty tough to complete this without seeing some of the data.  Can you provide a few lines of the .csv?  Are the states recorded as beginning of day/end of day?

Comment: @MarkMoretto i have modified the post with some data and output graph example

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I added an extra value set to show a little bit of diversity:

```
                datetime 3  switch 3  
0  2018-08-12 08:13:00.000         0  
1  2018-08-12 08:13:01.915         0  
2  2018-08-12 08:13:40.607         1  
3  2018-08-12 08:14:02.863         0  
4  2018-08-12 08:14:51.945         1  
5  2018-08-12 08:15:57.060         0  
6  2018-08-12 08:16:39.584         1  
7  2018-08-12 08:16:48.351         1  
8  2018-08-12 08:17:55.674         1  
9  2018-08-12 08:18:46.208         0  
10 2018-08-12 08:20:00.030         1  
11 2018-08-12 08:20:02.992         0  
12 2018-08-12 08:21:20.673         1  
13 2018-08-12 08:22:29.867         1  
14 2018-08-12 08:23:04.670         0  
15 2018-08-12 08:23:54.177         0
```

The script:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

root = r'C:\Users\...\...'
file_name = 'test_file.xlsx'
full_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)

### Import data
df = pd.read_excel(full_path)

### Get our switch columns
switch_cols = [i for i in df.columns.values.tolist() if i.startswith('switch')]

### Subset our main dataframe to include only switch columns
df1 = df.reindex(columns=switch_cols).copy()


def plot_results(dataframe):
    ### Get swtich column names into a list
    y_cols = [i for i in dataframe.columns.values.tolist()]

    ### Make the x-axis value set our dataframe axis values
    x_vals = dataframe.index.values.tolist()

    ### Create subplots based on the numer of swtich columns
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(y_cols), 1, sharex=True)

    ### Remove horizontal space between axes
    fig.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0)

    ### Iterate over enumerated list of switch columns
    for i, v in enumerate(switch_cols):
        ### set axes to plot values from a swtich set;
        ### Set drawstyle to 'steps-pre'
        axs[i].plot(x_vals, dataframe[v].values, drawstyle='steps-pre')

        ### Add padding to y-axis limits
        axs[i].set_ylim(-0.1, 1.1)

        ### Set y-axis label to switch column label
        axs[i].set_ylabel(v)

    ### Plot results
    plt.show()

plot_results(df1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I've tried your script but it's not working as i want.
I have tried it with this data, https://imgur.com/a/ZCzshEj
As you see the data is not aligned with the day hours